# React-select defaultValue is undefined when submitted

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I'm using `react-select` for a single select menu. The `defaultValue` appears to be displaying correctly when I edit the form, but when I submit the form the value returned is `undefined` if the selection is left unchanged. If I click the `defaultValue` then it works correctly when submitted. Is there an additional `prop` I'm missing to maintain the `defaultValue` through submission?

Code looks like this:

```
<Select
   closeMenuOnSelect={true}
   options={options()}
   defaultValue={defaultVal}
   className="basic-single"
   classNamePrefix="select"
/>
```

Where `options()` is a simple function to format the data like this:

```
  const options = [
    { value: "chocolate", label: "Chocolate" },
    { value: "strawberry", label: "Strawberry" },
    { value: "vanilla", label: "Vanilla" }
  ];
```

And `defaultVal` returns a single value by filtering `options`:

```
  let defaultVal = options().filter(
    (optionChoice) => optionChoice.label === props.choice
  );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using `react-hook-form` you need to utilize their `Controller` component to register your select with the form. Reference here: [Integrating Controlled Inputs](https://react-hook-form.com/get-started/#IntegratingControlledInputs).

The following component declaration illustrates wrapping a `react-select` component in a `react-hook-form` Controller component. It is registered with react-hook-form using `control={control}` and then renders the select through the Controller component's render prop.

You also need to let `react-hook-form` know when the selection changes by calling `handleChange` from the select on change. `handleChange()` in turn calls `react-hook-form`'s `setValue()` with the changed value and `shouldDirty: true` flagging the change.

```
const handleChange = (change) => {
  setValue("controlledSelect", change, {
    shouldDirty: true
  });
};
```

Working sandbox here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-select-with-react-hook-form-im9hi

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import Select from "react-select";

function ControlledSelect() {
  const { handleSubmit, control, setValue } = useForm();
  const [options, setOptions] = React.useState(initialOptions);

  const onSubmitData = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  const handleChange = (change) => {
    setValue("controlledSelect", change, {
      shouldDirty: true
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmitData)}>
        <Controller
          name="controlledSelect"
          control={control}
          defaultValue={options[1]}
          render={() => (
            <Select
              options={options}
              defaultValue={options[1]}
              onChange={handleChange}
            />
          )}
        />
        <button type="submit">Submit Select</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

Here's a rough snippet showing a working select. It looks like you want to declare the `defaultValue` as an index in the array: `defaultValue={defaultVal[0]}`. This will necessitate generating your formatted options array before render rather than passing a function, which is probably better regardless.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/emotion@9.2.12/dist/emotion.umd.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types@15.5.10/prop-types.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-input-autosize@2.2.1/dist/react-input-autosize.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-select@2.1.2/dist/react-select.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-standalone/6.26.0/babel.min.js"></script>
<div id="App"></div>
<script type="text/babel">
  const {useRef} = React;
  
  const options = [
    { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
    { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
    { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' }
  ]

function App() {
    const formRef = useRef();
    
    const submitForm = (e, ref) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(formRef.current.elements[1].value);

  }
  
    return (
      <form ref={formRef} onSubmit={submitForm}>
        <Select 
          name="select" 
          options={options} 
          defaultValue={options[1]} 
         />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    )    
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('App'));
 </script>
```

Comment: The `options` are in a function because they are sourced from an array that needs to be mapped to `value`/`label`. Even with this, the `defaultValue` is working and showing in the `console`, but when submitted the value is `undefined`. I am also using `react-hook-form`, so I'm not sure if that might be part of the problem.

Comment: Yes, `react-hook-form` changes things. I've edited my answer to explain and linked a working codesandbox.

Comment: thanks, I had most of what you included besides the `handleChange` function. I'm still not getting it to work, but I think it might have to due with storing `options` as a function. I'm going to try to store the options  using the `useState` hook as you have done.

Comment: I do think it makes sense to have the options array at least stored in a variable if not a state object. Calling `setValue()` on the form is really at the heart of it though. Without it react-hook-form works hard to avoid renders and so will not register changes on controlled inputs unless told. The `shouldDirty` flag is not strictly necessary here as the select handles it's own display, but in the case of a controlled text input you would need to send it to see the new value displayed correctly in the input.

Comment: One thing I was missing - I was only including the `defaultValue` prop in the `<Select/>` but not in the `<Controller/>`. Once I did that, the rest worked. Why does the `defaultValue` need to be duplicated in the parent and child component?

Comment: They are two separate components. You can actually omit it from either, but each has its own consequence: if you leave it off the Select, then there is no initial value set, but the Controller will have a (hidden) initial value; if you leave off the Controller the Select will display an initial value but until you change the selection (trigger the onChange) the Controller will be empty. Ultimately it is the Controller that is sending values along and the Select that is providing the interface. Glad you got it working!